# Copying file - is not a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why can't I copy *.dat file to another directory? My part of .sh script is:

```
cd $directory/

dat_file=$(find "$directory" -name '*.dat' -exec basename {} \;)    #find *.dat file
chmod 700 $directory/$dat_file  #changing its permission to be copied

cp $directory/$dat_file $second_dir/$dat_file           #copying .dat file
```

In output I have: (...) is not a directory.

This code works when I execute script via cygwin on Windows, but doesn't execute on linux machine.

Comment: Why not just something like this: `find "$directory" -name '*.dat' -exec cp -t "$second_directory" {} +`

Comment: @PesaThe Brilliant. You may post an answer and explain the use of `+` . This is an ideal use case for `+` imho.

Comment:  Quote, quote, quote your vars / gently down the stream... 

Answer (score 4):

`find ... -exec` can copy files directly:

```
find "$directory" -name '*.dat' -exec cp -t "$second_dir" {} +
```

---

From `man find`:

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the
>   selected files, but the  command
>                 line  is  built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of
>                 the command will be much less than the number of matched files.

`+` is preferred here because if `find` finds more files matching your conditions, the line will be built as follows:

```
cp -t "$second_dir" file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Unlike with the `-exec command {} ;` variant which invokes `cp` for each file.

Answer (score 3):

There may be more than one issue:

- After the first line, your working directory is `$directory`. Unless `$directory` is an absolute path, `find` will try to search in `$directory/$directory`, which probably does not exist.
- `chmod` and `cp` will not work when `find` returns more than one file, because `$directory` is only prepended to the first file.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following command:

```
dat_file=$(find "$directory" -name '*.dat' -exec cp -t "$second_directory" {} +)
```

But I got this information:

```
cp: will not overwrite just-created `$second_dir/dat_file.dat' with `$directory/dat_file.dat'
```

and the script stops in this place. In $directory is only one *.dat file, in second directory there is no any *.dat file before copy operation. 
I need an $ pointer, because this pointer is needed further.

Comment: Are you still using your command `cp $directory/$dat_file $second_dir/$dat_file` afterwards? `find` command does the copying for you. There is no need to do it yourself.

Comment: I am not using this command, but after command `cd second_dir/` I have to use `dat_file=$(find "$second_dir" -name '*.dat' -exec basename {} \;)` , because if I don't do this, the script won't find file. It is needed for further grepping file.

Comment: And I have still output `cp: will not overwrite just-created '/second_dir/dat_file.dat' with 'directory/dat_file.dat'`

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved. In $directory was additional temp directory with additional *.dat file, and `find` function returned 2 files instead of 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `cd "$directory"` (and even less with incorrect quotes) and generally your scripts usually don't need to `cd` anywhere.

If the `chmod` is really necessary, a plain `find -exec` may not suffice... but a slightly more complex one will do.

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.dat' -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        chmod 700 "$f"
        cp "$f" "$0"
    done' "$second_dir" {} +
```

In other words, we pass the found files to a simple in-line shell script. Somewhat hackishly, we pass in the destination directory as `$0` (which would conventionally contain the script's name, but it doesn't have one here, anyway).

Pay attention to the quoting; a file or directory name should basically never go unquoted.